# For python library on WIn10, why can't be imported through VS 2017 but Ok with CMD?

Tags: python, visual-studio

It is very weird, As I could import library with CMD terminate, but not with python on VS2017. And I am pretty sure the environment used are the same.

[import failed in VS2017 TERMINAL CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pU7i.jpg)

[suceeded in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISqAZ.jpg)

The most weird thing is that the lib I want to import did pop up when I am typing it in Vs2017 terminal.